# (Pre-calculus) Methodology for solving with fraction

Tags: algebra-precalculus

$ 2 {3\over 5} - {1\over 5} * {2\over 3}$

Can someone show me their working out on how to solve this problem?

Regards.

Answer (score 1):

$${1\over 3}* {2\over 5}={2\over 15}$$
$$2 {3\over 5} = {(5*2 +3)\over 5} = {13\over 5} = {13*3\over 5*3} = {39\over 15}$$
$${39\over 15} - {2\over 15} = {37\over 15}$$

**NOTE:**

Fractions of the form $a\frac{b}{c}$ are called mixed fractions.  $a\frac{b}{c}$ is nothing but $a+\frac{b}{c}$.

Comment: I suppose I miss a notation. What does represent $2 {3\over 5}$ ? I am serious. Thanks.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici Fractions of such form are called mixed fractions.It actually means $2+\frac{3}{5}$.

Comment: Thanks. It is the first time I see this notation. At all ages, we learn ! Cheers.

Comment: Yes. Learning is all that matters no matter the age ! An up vote would be appreciated though!

Comment: You go it, indeed !

Answer (score 1):

$\large 2\frac{3}{5}-\frac{1}{5}*\frac{2}{3}$, here $\large2\frac{3}{5}$ can also be written as $\large\frac{13}{5}$ as we multiply $2$ with $5$ and then add $3$ to get the numerator and the denominator remains as it is.

So it is, $\large\frac{13}{5}-\frac{1}{5}*\frac{2}{3}$,

The order of precedence or order of operation is as follows:

1. bigger brackets
2. smaller brackets
3. division
4. multiplication
5. addition
6. subtraction

So in present case we first multiply $\large\frac{1}{5}$ with $\large \frac{2}{3}$ and then subtract the reseult from $\large\frac{13}{5}$, hence, it is

$\large\frac{13}{5}-\frac{2}{15}=\frac{39-2}{15}=\frac{37}{15}$